# Showing a single record in datagridview from access database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

What I have is a small application that has a datagridview and an Access DB.  There are 10 records in the database and they all show up in the datagridview when the app is launched.  I need to be able to do two things:

1. I need to be able to enter an id number in a textbox and have JUST that record show in the DGV.
2. I need to be able to have it show all the records again (using a different click event of course).

I am able to choose the record with this:

```
Dim row As DataRow
        row = ProductsDataSet.tblProducts.FindByItemNum(txtNumber.Text)
```

but I am unable to figure out how to show just that record in the DGV.
(Let me clarify...I THINK I am choosing the record simply because no exceptions are being thrown).

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

John

Comment: Just apply/remove a filter to the DefaultView of the datasource that is binded to the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to set the dataSource of your dataGridView to the data you'd like to display. Below is an implementation using dataTables.

```
Class MyForm

Dim dataTableAll, dataTableOneID, As DataTable

Sub show1ID_Click
Dim id As Integer = InputBox("Enter ID")
dataTable2 = dataTable1.Select("[ID] = id").CopyToTable
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTableOneID
End Sub

Sub showAll_Click
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTableAll
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Greg, thank you so much for your quick reply.  I am still having trouble though because I can't seem to find the name of "dataTable1" (I don't know the name of my datatable and can't seem to find it)

Comment: Sorry my edited answer had failed to rename both occurrences of the table name. Does the above work for you now? Note that dataTableAll is just the dataTable you'd already have, presumably filled from your access DB.